# JDA Will not register my event(Discord Bot Java)

Tags: java, discord-jda

I've been having a problem with registering JDA events. Everytime I start the bot, it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MI6j.png). Can someone help me with this please?

Here's my Main code:

```
import Events.Information;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Activity;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.ChannelType;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Message;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.MessageChannel;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.ReadyEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class Main {
    public static String prefix = "!";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {
        JDABuilder jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("I inserted bot key here");
        jda.setActivity(Activity.watching("baldness"));

        jda.addEventListeners(new Information());

        jda.build();

    }
}
```

Here's my Information class code:

```
package Events;

import com.sun.tools.javac.Main;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;

public class Information {
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent e) {
        String[] args = e.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");

        if (args[0].equals("!commands")) {
            EmbedBuilder info = new EmbedBuilder();
            info.setTitle("Commands");
            info.setDescription("!info - Pops up with this!");
            info.setColor(0xf45642);
            info.setFooter("Bot created by Jason", e.getMember().getUser().getAvatarUrl());

            e.getChannel().sendTyping().queue();
            e.getChannel().sendMessage(info.build()).queue();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my layering of classes and packages:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STzaO.png)

Comment: Add `extends ListenerAdapter` to the listener class.

Comment: Also, I would recommend you to use `@Override` in order to detect such issues at compile-time.

Comment: Holy crap, tysm <3. I've been stuck on this for 2 days now .-.